# iOS Framework distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I built a framework for a client and they plan on distributing to their clients to add in their apps. I want to be able to distribute a single framework where they add it to their app and are able to run on simulator and device. Looking at combining using lipo, called fat frameworks, are getting rejected by Apple. So what are my options to have a single framework that dev can incorporate that will work on both sim and device?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this creates a combined "Fat" framework that Apple has been rejecting upload for having simulator slices.

http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216

Comment: the radar you referenced is two years old...

Answer (score 0):

In custom framework procedure need to build separately for both simulator and device.

Simulator - compile separately

Device - compile separately

1. Merge the framework for simulator and device is possible by libo.
2. App Store reject the app merged framework (simulator  and device ) integrated application.
3. Possible to extract the simulator build from the merged framework by using script.
4. Framework sell / distribute to the client should take device builded framework only
5. Simulator build framework is using Developers testing purpose only
6. No other need to set any **certifications / code sign f**or framework compile. Because framework project won't run in device.